# How do you convert a " x × y^z " expression into a readable/sayable number?

Tags: numbers

I read an article explaining that the mass of earth is 6 × 10^24 kg, but this expression means nothing to me since I can't convert it into a number as I do not know what ^ is supposed to mean. How would I read or speak it?

Comment: When Y=10, you can simply write the X (6 in this case),and then write Z (24 in this csse) zeroes after it.

Comment: Six trillion trillion kilograms, 6 septillion kilograms, 6000 yottagrams.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s about mathematics and scientific notation.

Comment: That’s a yotta grams!

Comment: Ex times wye to the power of zee. In the specific case, six times 10 to the 24th kilograms of mass.

Comment: @Jim — wouldn't an answer be on topic if, as in the title, it explained how to read or say the expression without explaining what it meant mathematically?

Comment: @David The OP seems to be interested in getting the number from 6 × 10^24 instead of reading it. I don't think this question is about English Language and Usage.

Comment: /'sɪksˌtaimz 'tɛndəðə 'twəniˌforθ 'kɪləˌgræms/

Answer (score 3):

Unformatted expression:

> 6 × 10^24 kg

Formatted expression:

> 6 × 10<sup>24</sup> kg

Spoken:

> Six times ten to the power of twenty-four kilograms

Comment: “*Six times ten to the twenty-fourth*” is probably a much more common verbalization.

Comment: @Jim — certainly an alternative — not sure whether more or less common. Am of the opinion that it is inferior in terms of clarity.